decoding json changing value and encoding in scala
I have this
request
                  .get(uri"$configurationEndpoint")
                  .header("Authorization", s"Bearer $token")
                  .send(backend)
                  .flatMap(configurationResponse => {
                    if (configurationResponse.code.equals(StatusCode.Ok)) {
                      decode[Json](configurationResponse.body) match {
                        case Right(value) => 
updatedJson = value.copy(bulkApi = true)

As you see, what I want to do is take the original json sent except I add a value if it doesn't exist or change it, how can I do this?
I have tried a few things such as the following but it did not work
value.deepMerge(Json.obj("bulkApi" -> bulkApi))


What http library and what json library do you use? How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Looks like its json play => play.api.libs.json

I'm willing to use any but currently using io.circe

Can you clarify why you say it doesn't work? How are you testing this? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example without all the noise of the request stuff? Where are the types you're using defined?..

So essentially I am calling a rest API that returns a config file, the file has different variables each time so I cannot make a Response case class to decode it. Instead I want to use a generic io.circe.json. So when I call the endpoint and get a response, I do this
.flatMap(configurationResponse => {
if (configurationResponse.code.equals(StatusCode.Ok)) {
decodeJson
No, I want to take a variable named BulkApi in the configurationResponse if it exists and set it to true in an updated json object

So minimal reproducible example would be to call an API, get a json back, decode it into a json(I used io.circe.json) like this, decodeJson, take the the json and say you want to change jsonVal, either change it or add it value if it doesn't exist

@FriendlyProgrammer if you are using circe, then all you need to do is: value.mapObject(_.add(key = "bulkApi", value = Json.True))
